# group data by their keys in MapReduce MongoDB

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mapreduce

i am trying MapReduce program in MongoDB to find mutual friend, i have following data obtained after sorting the key in mongoDB

```
{"user" : " Hari","friend" : "Shiva",
 "friendList": ["Hanks"," Tom"," Karma"," Hari"," Dinesh"]}


 {"user" : "Hari","friend" : " Shiva",
  "friendList" : ["Karma"," Tom"," Ram"," Bindu"," Shiva",
                   " Kishna"," Bikash"," Bakshi"," Dinesh"]}
```

Now here i want to group these data set having same key into single group, using Javascript in map function before send key-value pairs to the reducers, how can i group data? For example i want output like

```
{"user" : " Hari","friend" : "Shiva",
 "friendList": ["Hanks"," Tom"," Karma"," Hari"," Dinesh"],["Karma"," Tom"," Ram"," Bindu"," Shiva"," Kishna"," Bikash"," Bakshi"," Dinesh"]}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can concat the `friendlist` array of the two records into a single array to create an object like this:

```
   {
  "_id": {
    "user": " Hari",
    "friend": "Shiva"
  },
  "value": {
    "friendList": [
      "Hanks",
      " Tom",
      " Karma",
      " Hari",
      " Dinesh",
      "Karma",
      " Tom",
      " Ram",
      " Bindu",
      " Shiva",
      " Kishna",
      " Bikash",
      " Bakshi",
      " Dinesh"
    ]
  }
}
```

See the code at https://jsfiddle.net/b6hxswvk/1/  to create this single object

If you want the `friendlist` to be a 2 dimensional array i.e. like this:

```
{
  "_id": {
    "user": " Hari",
    "friend": "Shiva"
  },
  "value": {
    "friendList": [
      [
        "Hanks",
        " Tom",
        " Karma",
        " Hari",
        " Dinesh"
      ],
      [
        "Karma",
        " Tom",
        " Ram",
        " Bindu",
        " Shiva",
        " Kishna",
        " Bikash",
        " Bakshi",
        " Dinesh"
      ]
    ]
  }
}
```

you can use the code at https://jsfiddle.net/b6hxswvk/2/

Comment: here i want output containing two array as i indicate above and i am using javascript for mapreduce functions  and i dont know more in JavaScript so can i get it as formatted above?

Comment: This is not valid JSON: `{"friendList": ["Hanks"," Tom"," Karma"," Hari"," Dinesh"],["Karma"," Tom"," Ram"," Bindu"," Shiva"," Kishna"," Bikash"," Bakshi"," Dinesh"]}` so I created a single concatenated array. Please provide a valid JSON for the final `friendlist`

Comment: Also see edited answer to create a 2 dimensional `friendList`

Answer (score 1):

You can do simply `aggregation` where you can do `$group` based on **user** and **friend** fields.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
{$group:{
_id:{
       user:'$user',
       friend:'$friend'
    },
    friendList:{$push:'$friendList'}
}},

// project the fields as your wish
{$project:{
    user:'$_id.user',
    friend:'$_id.friend',
    friendList:'$friendList'
}}
])
```

Hope this aggregation pipeline can return you expected result

Answer (score 0):

Friend,  Why you want to take the pain of grouping the data values for a same key if the map reduce will be performing it by grouping the values of same key and giving to the reduce as key,list[values] ?

I strongly recommend you to perform the grouping task in your reducer instead of Map. the main reason behind it is that since map task reads record by record and performs collect operation, the burden of identifying the same key groups is taken by the algorithm and how to design the output with grouped values can be taken care by us in the reduce logic

you can take the output of the reducer for your further processing.

**Input:**

```
{"_id" : {"user" : " Hari","friend" : "Shiva"},
 "value" : {"friendList": ["Hanks"," Tom"," Karma"," Hari"," Dinesh"]}}


 {"_id" : {"user" : "Hari","friend" : " Shiva"},
  "value" : {"friendList" : ["Karma"," Tom"," Ram"," Bindu"," Shiva",
                             " Kishna"," Bikash"," Bakshi"," Dinesh"]}}
```

**Mapreduce Code :**

```
var mapper = function () {
    var key = {"user" : this.user, "friend" : this.friend};
    emit(key, {"value":{"friendList":this.friendList}});
};

var reducer = function(key, value){
var combinedfriendList = {"friendList":[]};

    for (var i in values) {
        var inter = values[i];
        for (var j in inter.friendList) {
            combinedfriendList.friendList.push(inter.friendList[j]);
        }
    }
return {"_id": {"user":key.user, "friend": key.friend}, "value":combinedfriendList};
};
```

**Expected output:**

```
{"_id" : {"user" : " Hari","friend" : "Shiva"},
 "value" : {"friendList": ["Hanks"," Tom"," Karma"," Hari"," Dinesh","Karma"," Tom"," Ram"," Bindu"," Shiva"," Kishna"," Bikash"," Bakshi"," Dinesh"]}}
```

Hope this is for some help.you can test it in your environment (alter if needed ) and share your feedback.

Comment: i have tried but could not get what i want.....i think you will be clear what i  am doing ...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38949291/group-document-by-their-key-in-monogodb-mapreduce...I highly appreciate your help my Friend..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39003704/mutual-friend-using-mapreduce-in-mongodb

Comment: @bikas please refer my rectent comments in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39003704/mutual-friend-using-mapreduce-in-mongodb ,hope that could help