# mutual friend using MapReduce in MongoDB

Tags: python, mongodb, mapreduce

i am trying MapReduce in MongoDB, i have MongoDB collection with following data type

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("57aea85af405910cfcd2bfeb"), "friendList" : [ "Karma", " Tom", " Ram", " Bindu", " Shiva", " Kishna", " Bikash", " Bakshi", " Dinesh" ], "user" : "Hari" }

{ "_id" : ObjectId("57aea85bf405910cfcd2bfec"), "friendList" : [ "Karma", " Sita", " Bakshi", " Hanks", " Shyam", " Bikash" ], "user" : "Howard" }

{ "_id" : ObjectId("57aea85cf405910cfcd2bfed"), "friendList" : [ "Dinesh", " Ram", " Hanks", " Bindu", " Howard", " Bikash", " Shyam", " Bakshi" ], "user" : "Sita" }

{ "_id" : ObjectId("57aea85cf405910cfcd2bfee"), "friendList" : [ "Hanks", " Tom", " Karma", " Hari", " Dinesh" ], "user" : "Shiva" }

{ "_id" : ObjectId("57aea85cf405910cfcd2bfef"), "friendList" : [ "Bakshi", " Kishna", " Hanks", " Shiva", " Bindu", " Hari", " Karma", " Sita" ], "user" : "Dinesh" }
```

**My Code**

```
map = Code("""
           function () {
               for (var i=0; i<this.friendList.length; i++)
            {
            var friendValue = this.friendList[i];
            var userValue = this.user;

            var tempUserValue = userValue.toLowerCase().trim();
            var tempFriendValue = friendValue.toLowerCase().trim();

                if(tempUserValue>tempFriendValue)
                    {
                    var temp = userValue;
                    userValue = friendValue;
                    friendValue = temp; 
                    }

            var key = {"user" : userValue, "friend" : friendValue};


            emit(key, {"friendList":this.friendList});              
            }

                   }""") 

reduce = Code("""
            function(key, values){
            var combinedfriendList = {"friendList":[]};

            for (var i in values){
                var inter = values[i];
                    for(var j in inter.friendList){
                        combinedfriendList.friendList.push(inter.friendList[j]);
                        }
                        }


            return {"_id": {"user":key.user, "friend": key.friend}, "value":combinedfriendList};

            }""")
```

Here in map function, i have done sorting and also composite key is formed so that same key passes through same reducers i.e input to reduce() function

**Map() output:**

```
{"_id" : {"user" : "Dinesh","friend" : " Hari"},"value" : {"friendList" : ["Bakshi"," Kishna"," Hanks"," Shiva"," Bindu"," Hari"," Karma"," Sita"    ]}}
{"_id" : {"user" : "Dinesh","friend" : " Hari"},"value" : {"friendList" : ["Karma"," Tom"," Ram"," Bindu"," Shiva"," Kishna"," Bikash"," Bakshi"," Dinesh"]}}
```

And now in reducer i want to combined friendList having same key.But here my reduce function is not working?

**Expected Output**

```
{"_id" : {"user" : "Dinesh","friend" : " Hari"},"value" : {"friendList" : ["Bakshi"," Kishna"," Hanks"," Shiva"," Bindu"," Hari"," Karma"," Sita",
"Karma"," Tom"," Ram"," Bindu"," Shiva"," Kishna"," Bikash"," Bakshi"," Dinesh"]}}
```

Comment: bikas, I have one  clariffication , can you please let me know what is the type of 'value' variable in the reducer , i mean is it a single json object {} or array of values [] . If it is a single json object with children as key value pairs then in the place of 'for' loops , could you please try the different for format  i.e  ( for i in values )  because .length on object will not work if it is not array

Comment: Hope I am clear , to know what is  the type of `values` in the reducer , please do `console.log(values);` in reducer ,  I want to know if it prints like `{{"friendList":['asa','asa']},{"friendList":['asa','asa']}}` or `[{"friendList":['asa','asa']},{"friendList":['asa','asa']}]`. as you might already know , there is a big difference in both. if my doubt is  correct and it is printing  like former , then  `values.length` will not work in the for loop causing  reducer to fail. So we need to change `for( i=0;i<values.length;i++)` as `for( i in values)`

Comment: one small correction - it is `console.log(JSON.stringify(values));`

Comment: @Addy i am using  MapReduce in MongoDB with python so i cannot use console.log(JSON.stringify(values));

Comment: @Addy i have tried with for( i in values) also but it doesnot work. anything wrong in my reduce function?  as i have mention above my map() function gives output, as formatted above which is input to reduce() function. i am stuck a lot here ...please friend anything wrong here?

Comment: What are you trying to do here?